# Prove the derivative of the function $f:U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, where $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, is zero at a local minimum.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Say we have a function $f:U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ where $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Prove if f has a local minimum at $c \in U$ and $f$ is differentiable at $c$, then $f'(c) = 0$.

Outline of my attempt: Since $c$ is a local minimum there is an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $f(c+h) - f(c) \geq 0$ for all $h$ and $|h| < \epsilon$. Therefore the limit as $h \rightarrow 0$ of $\frac{f(c+h) - f(c)}{\|h\|}$ is $0$ and thus the derivative is $0$. However, this doesn't feel correct to me. One concern I had was, can I say the above limit approaches $0$?

Comment: You need to consider the limit at $c$ approaching from either sides. The derivative when approaching from left-side should be negative, that approaching from the right side should be positive as there is a local minimum

Comment: Thats what I did when $U$ was a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ but since the norm of $h$ is always positive, how can I do this in the vector case?

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We see by the first principles, that $f'(c)=\lim_{h\rightarrow0^+}\frac{f(c+he_i)-f(c)}{h}\leq 0$, and $f'(c)=\lim_{h\rightarrow0^-}\frac{f(c+he_i)-f(c)}{h}\ge 0$, thus $f'(c)=0$.

Here $e_i=(0,0,...,1,...,0)$ with $1$ in the $i$-th position.

We see this holds for all directions $e_i$, so $f$ is totally differentiable (or **differentiable**) and $f'(c)=0$.

Comment: However, $h$ is a vector so we would have to divide by its norm which is always positive. I see how your answer works when the domain is $\mathbb{R}$ but not when it is $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: $f$ is defined on $U\subset\Bbb R^n$

Comment: I have changed it to fit with $\mathbb { R^n }$

Comment: You do not need to restrict to basis vectors here:  $Df(a)(\vec{v}) \displaystyle\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h\vec{v})-f(a)}{h}$.  Then use your same argument with $h \to 0^+$ and $h \to 0^-$

Comment: But then there can be ambiguity with the direction of each derivative

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ has a local minimum at $c$, then for any $v ∈ ℝ^n$ with $\lVert v \rVert = 1$,

- $\lim_{t→0^+} \frac{f(c+tv) - f(c)}{t} ≥ 0$, and
- $\lim_{t→0^-} \frac{f(c+tv) - f(c)}{t} ≤ 0$.

But if $f$ is differentiable at $c$, both limits must be equal.

Comment: Why restrict to unit vectors?